# Calculation if results of model ranking could occur by chance alone

Tags: probability, predictive-models, validation, randomness

I have a prediction tool which ranks 56 models of proteins based on computation. I also have the correct ranking of those structures based on the closeness to actual structure of the protein. If I rank the structures based on my prediction method and compare them to the correct ranking, say 5 of top ten structures in the correct ranking appear in top ten of my predicted ranking. So my question is, how do I show that my prediction is significantly different than just selecting 10 structures randomly from the 56 models and 5 of them be in the top ten of the correct ranking just by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is sort of an arbitrary question. Why not just do significance of rank correlation on all the answers versus all the predictions, i.e., Spearman rank correlation? That would show how significant all the rankings are.